# RSpec "let" method incorrectly returns nil

Tags: rspec

I am running into a strange behavior in my RSpec test using `let`. I have never had a problem using `let` so that's why this is so strange. In the following test, the `my_model` `let` definition is returning nil:

```
describe '.process' do
  let(:my_model){ Fabricate(:my_model) }

  it 'doesnt work' do
    # my_model returns nil but it should be returning the fabricated model
    my_model = Processor.process(my_model)
    my_model.special_attribute.should == 'foo'
  end

  it 'works' do
    my_model = Fabricate(:my_model)
    # my_model is now correctly fabricated
    my_model = Processor.process(my_model)
    my_model.special_attribute.should == 'foo'
  end
end
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you're using a left-hand assignment to `my_model` *before* `my_model` is invoked. `let` creates a method called `my_method`, but by assigning to a value called `my_method` first, you're shadowing the method with a nil local variable.

You should use a different variable name there on the first non-comment line of `it "doesn't work"`. If you run this test:

```
it 'doesnt work' do
  puts defined?(my_model)
  my_model = (puts defined?(my_model)) && process(my_model)
end
```

You'll get the following output:

```
method
local-variable
```

As soon as you assign to a value (rather than calling a `my_model=` method, which doesn't exist in this scope), you create a local variable which will shadow the method and prevent it from being called. You can illustrate this easily in plain Ruby:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    "BAR"
  end

  def run
    bar = bar.downcase
  end
end

Foo.new.run

# bar.rb:11:in `run': undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
#    from bar.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

[This blog post](http://coffeepowered.net/2009/03/02/syntactic-sugar-will-occassionally-kick-your-puppies/) might help illuminate the issue further.

Comment: That was it, thanks! I guess I thought it would evaluate right to left but that's obviously not the case.

Comment: It does, kind of, except that the local variables get defined when the line is reached rather than as it's evaluated. I used to remember why, but I'd have to go to the VM source for specifics.